# create a method with return using a delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

working on xcode I realized that if I create a non-void method, I call it from a class / method, the result is processed optimally only if the action is immediate. I tried to do a test by inserting a delay and I realized that it no longer works.
I will write down here the example that I created:

**Class A**

```
//--------------------CLASS A
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   i = 0;
   Class *classB = [[Class alloc] init];
   i = [classB method1];
   [self performSelector:@selector(method3) withObject:NULL afterDelay:1.8];
}

-(void)method3 {
   NSLog(@"i = %i",i); // i = 0
}
```

**Class B**

```
//--------------------CLASS B    
-(int)method1 {
  [self performSelector:@selector(method2) withObject:NULL afterDelay:1];
  return a;
}

-(void)method2 {
  a = 800;
}
```

Obviously my problem is not something so trivial but I tried to make it easy to get an answer as thoroughly as possible, I was advised to use modal methods but I don't think that's the solution I was looking for.

What could I do to solve this?!

Comment: the best approach for this is to use an asynchronous call that waits for the task to finish, you can do this pretty easy with GCD.

Comment: you may be a little more specific please?

Comment: michaels approach is better, with a delegate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need is a better understanding of asynchronous methods. In your `method1`, the variable `a` is never altered -- all you are doing is scheduling `method2` to be called in the future and then returning the current state of variable `a`.

In Objective-C, there are a few different ways you can solve this problem. People most commonly use `protocols` and `delegates` to solve this issue. Here is a basic [intro to protocols and delegates](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html). Basically, you would want your class A object to be a delegate of your class B object. You could also use [NSNotifications](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html), although you should probably understand the usage of protocols and delegates (they are very important in Objective-C) before moving on to notifications and blocks.

Comment: thanks so much for the links, I hope we can solve everything by using delegates

Comment: @Filoo A delegate is a "helper object" that can customize the behavior of another object by making decisions on its behalf. Unless ClassB is meant to be a class that's reused in a number of different situations, delegation isn't what you want. You've already *got* an object, and you're presumably looking to just return some data to it. An instance variable or property is probably all you need.

Comment: yes sure I had even thought about a property, but since I was starting to use these methods I wanted to understand if there was a way to do it, thanks anyway for the info

Answer (score 2):

> What could I do to solve this?!

Where do you want to return the value *to*? In your example, `method1` will complete long before `method2` is ever invoked. If you want to preserve the value calculated by `method2`,  you'll typically have that method store the value in one of ClassB's instance variables and possibly call some other method to continue processing.

If you really need `method1` to return the result from `method2`, you'll need to call it synchronously (i.e. without `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`). In this case, consider a) why you need the delay at all; and b) if you should perhaps be calling `method1` after a delay instead of `method2`.

We'll be able to provide much better help if you can explain what the real-world problem that you're trying to solve is.